# Which event will be throw while the form is reloading after hiding the form?

Tags: c#

I am having a form in my application Form1. A thread is running in this form. When i am showing the next form Form2, I am hiding this form and aborting the thread. 
When I am showing the parent form again , i need to restart the thread again.which event
in the main form I can write thread restart code?

Comment: hmm. I never tried it but, did u try VisibleChanged event?

Answer (score 2):

While the [`VisibleChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) or [`Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) events may do this, I have to wonder why you don't just do it explicitly - it's your code that will be showing the form again, isn't it? Why not just create a new thread as part of the code that gets executed at that point?

As a side note, if you really *are* aborting the thread (with `Thread.Abort`) it would be worth moving to a more graceful shutdown procedure, setting a flag which the thread checks periodically. Hard aborts of threads are prone to leaving the application in an unknown state.